# Scope model values and count in a single query | Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have models as follows:

```
class QuestionResult
  belongs_to :test_result
  belongs_to :test

  scope :answered -> { where("answered = ?",true) }
  scope :unanswered, -> { where("answered IS NULL OR answered != ?",true) }
end

class TestResult
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :question_results
end
```

Now I need these values:

```
test_result.question_results.answered.count
test_result.question_results.unanswered.count
test_result.review_questions.count
```

`review_questions` is a column in `test_results` table.

So I need the value of `count` of `review_questions` in the `test_results` table and values of the `counts` of `scopes`: `answered` and `unanswered` in the associated `question_results` table.

There is no column `unanswered` in the `question_results` table. It is only a `scope` but there is a column with the name `answered`.

At present, I am querying these values as shown above.

Is there any way that I can do the same in a single query?

**Update 1**

I am able to combine the first two queries into a single query without using `scopes` in query as below:

```
test_result.question_results.group(:answered).count
```

How can I combine `test_result.review_questions.count` query into the updated query?

**Update 2**

```
SELECT 
test_results.id, 
sum(if (question_results.answered = 1, 1, 0)) as answered, 
sum(if (question_results.answered = 0 or question_results.answered is null, 1, 0)) as unanswered, 
test_results.review_questions 
FROM test_results 
INNER JOIN question_results ON question_results.section_result_id = test_results.id 
WHERE test_results.id = test.test_result.last.id;
```

This is the working `sql` query. What is its equivalent `rails activerecord` query?

Comment: What do you mean with _the value in the test_results table and value of the count in the associated table_?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it now.

Comment: What RDMBS are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with _value of count of review_questions in the test_results_. If it's a column in the table itself why are you going to count it?

About the answered and unanswered scopes, without CTE you can use sub-queries:

```
SELECT
  test_results.id,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM question_results q
   WHERE q.answered = true
   AND q.test_result_id = test_results.id) AS total_answered,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM question_results q
   WHERE q.answered = false
   OR q.answered IS NULL
   AND q.test_result_id = test_results.id) AS total_unanswered
FROM test_results
WHERE test_results.id = id
```

The further you can go using Rails with this is storing each sub-select and pass it within the ActiveRecord `select` method:

```
answered = '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question_results q WHERE q.answered = true AND q.test_result_id = test_results.id) AS answered'
unanswered = '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question_results q WHERE q.answered = false OR q.answered IS NULL AND q.test_result_id = test_results.id) AS unanswered'
TestResult.select(:id, answered, unanswered).where(id: id).as_json
```

---

As seen in the discussion, you can just "convert" the raw SQL you're using with ActiveRecord methods (sadly, not completely):

```
TestResult
  .select(
    :id,
    :review_questions,
    'SUM(IF(question_results.answered = true, 1, 0)) AS answered', 
    'SUM(IF(question_results.answered = true OR question_results.answered IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS unanswered')
  .joins(:question_results)
  .group(:id)
  .as_json
```

Comment: `answered` and `unanswered` are scopes of `question_result`. So while doing the above map I am again hitting the database twice right?

Comment: ` _value of count of review_questions in the test_results_` This is my mistake. I did not mention it clearly in the question. I just want the value of `review_questions` from `test_results` for that particular `test_result instance`.

Comment: No @Lax_Sam, I'm not using the scopes there, as you see the query is a bit complex and Active Record doesn't have full support for this, so you'll end with a bunch of interpolated strings just to use them. The map is used because AR returns an array of test_results, the aliased aren't shown until you invoke them. And no, isn't hitting the database twice. `review_questions ` can be easily added to the select.

Comment: Oh ok. Got it. In the above code, `select(:answered, :unanswered)` throws an error because the column `answered` is in `question_results` table and not in `section_results` table. I have also added the exact working `sql` query to the question now.

Comment: But in the answer, `TestResult.select(:id, answered, unanswered)`, answered and unanswered are the local variables defined before passed to the AR select method. They aren't symbols used to get columns in the test_results table.

Comment: I am getting this error if I do the above: `NameError: undefined local variable or method answered for main:Object`. 
It works when I do this: 

`TestResult.select(:id).where(id: 100).map do |test_result| { answered: test_result.question_results.answered.count } end`

Comment: You must define both variables first. See the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203648/discussion-between-lax-sam-and-sebastian-palma).

Answer (score 0):

This is one option.

```
answered_count = test_result.question_results.answered.count
unanswered_count = TestResult.count - answered_count
```

Also, I'd recommend removing the `belongs_to :test` on QuestionResult. TestResult already has a foreign key reference to :test, so the QuestionResult's association with both the `:test` and the `:test_result` is redundant.

Or,

```
belongs_to :test, :through => :test_result
```

can get rid of the redundant foreign key as well